# Question/Answer icons are fuzzy on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, icons

The *Ask Question* and *Add an answer* icons appear to be upscaled from either HDPI or XHDPI and seem very fuzzy on an XXHDPI Nexus 5.

Can we have proper image for higher resolution buckets?

[image: fuzzy Q icon]

<sup>(Click the image to view its full-size)</sup>

Comment: Might as well add XXXHDPI! ;)

Comment: I've closed this as no longer reproducible since the apps themselves were discontinued years ago (even if you still have the app on your device, this bug won't be fixed).